# Pandas split column of lists into multiple new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to break a column of list value into different column.
Can you guys please give me some guidance how to do that? Thanks
In the original dataframe, there is no column name(Column 1   Column2). I just name it in order to have better understanding on this issue.

```
Before:
Column 1   Column2
   A       ['2.49', '-2.18', '-3.79']
   B       ['2.56', '-3.02', '-4.92']
   C       ['-0.09', '-1.73', '-3.47']

After:
Column 1   Column2      Column3       Column4
   A       '2.49'       '-2.18'       '-3.79'
   B       '2.56'       '-3.02'       '-4.92'
   C       '-0.09'      '-1.73'       '-3.47'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: `pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.column2.tolist())],axis = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Column2': [['2.49', '-2.18', '-3.79'], ['2.56', '-3.02', '-4.92'], ['-0.09', '-1.73', '-3.47']]
                  }
                 )

pd.concat([df['Column 1'],
           pd.DataFrame(df['Column2'].to_list(), columns=['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'])],
          axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the values of Column 2 are list you don't actually need splits or anything like that, just select the element that you want. So, column3 will be list element[1], column4 list element[2], and then lastly convert column2 to list element[0]:

```
df['Column 3'] = df['Column 2'][1]
df['Column 4'] = df['Column 2'][2]
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'][0]
```

I would recommend to rename them so you don't overwrite the 'Column2' and keep all the columns.